# Exclude whole files based on configuration from build in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-process

I have three different configurations on my project, all three do not require all files to be build into the application. Actually I'd prefer if I could exclude those files from the build, which would make my application a little more lightweight.

What I'm looking for is `#if MYCONFIG` or `#if DEBUG` statement but for files. I've already read that this can be accomplished by manually editing the csproj file, but I can't find that anymore...and are there other ways?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two different ways:
In your csproj files, you will have sections that look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Helper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What you can do is set up a new project configuration (*Build* menu, *Configuration Manager*, select *New* from the *Active solution configuration* dropdown), then manually change the ItemGroup node to this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'MyNewConfiguration' ">
    <Compile Include="Helper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The second way, as you referred to in your question, is to use conditional debug symbols. At the top of your file, have the statement

```
#if MYDEBUGSYMBOL
```

and at the bottom have

```
#endif
```

then you can define the debug symbols; right clickon your project file, select *Properties*, go to the *Build* tab, and enter the debug symbol in the *Conditional compilation symbols* textbox.

I would probably stick with the first method.

Comment: Is this also possible with the old VS2008 project files for C projects?